# Angular SPA over ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I ve read a lot of documents from here about it same. But finally in the part of trying for myself I miss something. Here is my scenario.

I am working over ASP.NET Core Template. Begin as it:

File: Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;
using SMT000000.Data;
using SMT000000.Models;
using SMT000000.Services;

namespace SMT000000
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, 
    reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", 
    optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "SPA", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
}
}
```

Then I have add a simple controller with a view dominated by a diferent Layout.

SPAController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace SMT000000.Controllers
{
    public class SPAController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
Layout=_LayoutSPA.cshtml
}
```

_LayoutSPA.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - SPA LAYOUT</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-
version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have add package.json, tsconfig.json and webpack.config.js to work with webpack for the Angular 2 part.

```
 {
"name": "SMT000000",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
 "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
},
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/common": "^2.4.5",
 "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.5",
 "@angular/core": "^2.4.5",
 "@angular/forms": "^2.4.5",
 "@angular/http": "^2.4.5",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.5",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.5",
 "@angular/platform-server": "^2.4.5",
 "@angular/router": "^3.4.5",
 "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
 "angular2-platform-node": "~2.0.11",
 "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
 "angular2-universal": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
 "angular2-universal-patch": "^0.2.1",
 "angular2-universal-polyfills": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
 "aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.0",
 "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.17",
 "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0",
 "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
 "css": "^2.2.1",
 "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
 "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
 "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
 "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
 "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc",
 "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
 "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
 "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
 "jquery": "^2.2.1",
 "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
 "preboot": "^4.5.2",
 "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
 "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
 "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
 "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
 "typescript": "^2.2.1",
 "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
 "webpack": "^2.2.0",
 "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2",
 "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
 "zone.js": "^0.7.8"
  },
   "devDependencies": {
   "@types/chai": "^3.4.34",
   "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.37",
   "chai": "^3.5.0",
   "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
   "karma": "^1.3.0",
   "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
   "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
   "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
   "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
    {
 "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "node" ]
  },
  "exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ],
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {

const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
const sharedConfig = {
    stats: { modules: false },
    context: __dirname,
    resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles 
requests for this URL prefix
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientAppSPA/, use: ['awesome-
typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] },
            { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'] },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 
 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
};

// Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-client': './ClientAppSPA/boot-client.ts' },
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [

        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            filename: '[file].map', 
            moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, 
'[resourcePath]') 
        })
    ] : [

        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ])
});


const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
    entry: { 'main-server': './ClientAppSPA/boot-server.ts' },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./ClientAppSPA/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
            sourceType: 'commonjs2',
            name: './vendor'
        })
    ],
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientAppSPA/dist')
    },
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
});

return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

And finally, the View I render is:

```
    @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<app asp-prerender-module="ClientAppSPA/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>

<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@section scripts {
<script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

Project Tree:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By6uV1HGsProVGRLQmczbVZ1d0U/view?usp=sharing

"The Thing" is "working" but first I had problems for loading angular components if I had templates as html files instead being implicits in the component. (I think a missed route there) but trying to use implicits throw the next exception. I feel as the document it is never ready. I know I am doing bad but practicing. If someone could guide me. Cheers.

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO2J4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wanted to make use of the angular cli so I took a different approach.

Project can be found here: https://github.com/wickdninja/DotNetCoreAngular2Demo

## ASP.NET Core / Angular 2 via CLI Quick Start

### Disclaimer

#### This guide was created using the following versions, and provides no guarentee for compatibility with any other versions.

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 7.4.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.6
@angular/compiler: 2.4.6
@angular/core: 2.4.6
@angular/forms: 2.4.6
@angular/http: 2.4.6
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.6
@angular/router: 3.4.6
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.6
```

### Install Project Dependencies

- [ASP.NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core)
- [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org)
- Yoeman

  - `$ npm i -g yo`
- ASP.NET Core Generator

  - `$ npm i -g generator-aspnet`
- Angular CLI

  - `$ npm i -g angular-cli`

### Generate Project

- `$ yo aspnet`

  - Select Web Api Project
  - Name application `DemoApp`
  - `$ cd DemoApp`

### Server Setup

- Open project.json

  - Exclude `node_modules` from compilation
  - Add the following to `"buildOptions"`

  `"compile": {
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }`

  - Add StaticFiles dependency
  - Add `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0"` to `dependencies`
- Restore dependencies

  - `$ dotnet restore`
- Configure server to handle api routes and client side routes

  - Open `Startup.cs`
  - Locate the `Configure` method add the following to it

    - Configure CORS

    `app.UseCors(cors =>
    cors
      .AllowAnyHeader()
      .AllowAnyMethod()
      .AllowAnyOrigin()
    );`

    - Route requests to root for client side spa

    `app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
    await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("passing to client");
        context.Request.Path = "/";
        await next();
    }
    });`

    - Enable static files (without allow directory browsing)

    `app.UseFileServer(enableDirectoryBrowsing: false);`

    - Setup routes for API

    `app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
    routes.MapRoute(
          name: "api",
          template: "api/{controller=Version}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });`
- Verify changes by building server

  - `$ dotnet build`

### Client Setup

- Create a new angular 2 app using the angular CLI

  - `$ ng new DemoApp`
- Move angular app to project's root directory

  - `$ mv DemoApp/* .`
  - This command moves everything except "dot files"
  - Move `.editorconfig`
  - `$ mv DemoApp/.editorconfig .`
  - Move git repo
  - `$ mv DemoApp/.git .`
  - Copy contents of `DemoApp/.gitignore` into `./gitignore`
  - Find and uncomment `#wwwroot`

    - Remove the `#` character
  - Remove angular generated app root
  - `$ rm -rf DemoApp`
- Configure Angular CLI build output

  - Open `angular-cli.json`
  - Update `outDir`

    - `"outDir": "wwwroot"`
- Test client app build

  - `$ ng build`

### Build Scripts

- Open `project.json`

  - Replace `scripts` with the following

  `"scripts": {
          "ng": "ng",
          "prerestore": "npm install",
          "restore": "dotnet restore",
          "postrestore": "npm run build",
          "prestart": "npm run restore",
          "start": "dotnet run",
          "client": "ng serve",
          "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
          "test": "ng test",
          "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
          "e2e": "protractor",
          "clean": "rimraf -- wwwroot",
          "postclean": "ng build",
          "prebuild": "npm run clean",
          "build": "dotnet build",
          "clean:prod": "rimraf -- wwwroot",
          "postclean:prod": "ng build --prod",
          "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:prod",
          "build:prod": "dotnet publish -c release"
        }`

### Run App

- `$ npm start`

  - Wait for server to start
  - `Now listening on: http://localhost:5000`
  - Verify client application works
  - Open browser and navigate to `http://localhost:5000`

    - Notice `app works!` text from our AppComponent is displayed on the screen
  - Verify API is working
  - Navigate to `http://localhost://5000/api/values`

    - The response should be the following JSON `["value1","value2"]`

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Angular 2 (built with Webpack) with ASP.NET Core but with different approach. Instead of using Razor like you are doing, I return the content of the static index.html file:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return Content(GetContent(), new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
}
```

Webpack is configured to output the built files to *wwwroot* instead of *dist*. Of course you can add a build step to Webpack to copy content from *dist* to *wwwroot*.